# querySelectorAll() to html from another page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, selectors-api

Good morning,
I am geting html of another page by AJAX:

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest()
xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xml.readyState == 4) {
        // here I need to work with data
        // xml.responseText
    }
}
xml.open("GET", url, false);
xml.send(null)
```

How I can apply querySelectorAll() to html content of another page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create new document and put `responseText` into it. Then you can use `querySelectorAll()`. Here is your `onreadystatechange` function:

```
function () {
    if (xml.readyState == 4) {
        var container = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().documentElement;
        container.innerHTML = xml.responseText;
        var nodeList = container.querySelectorAll('selector');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your response is valid XML, you can try `xml.responseXml`.

If that's not the case, you might consider using a `DocumentFragment`:

```
var doc = document.createDocumentFragment();
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = xml.responseText;
doc.appendChild(div);

var nodes = doc.querySelectorAll("...");
```

Comment: Could you explain practical difference between `createDocumentFragment()` and `createHTMLDocument()`?

Comment: @Pavlo Good question! According to [MDN's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument#Example), you also have to copy ("import") the created document into the current website's document if you want to display the HTML eventually.