# How to get querySelectorAll from another webpage?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, webapi

I'm trying to get data from another webpage, using the HTML DOM. I tried code from another StackOverflow question ([querySelectorAll() to html from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583396/queryselectorall-to-html-from-another-page)) but it's not working for me:

```js
let url = "[URL here]"
let xml = new XMLHttpRequest()
xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xml.readyState == 4) {
    let container = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().documentElement
    container.innerHTML = xml.responseText
    let nodeList = container.querySelectorAll('.msDetails-Row')
    console.log(nodeList)
  }
}
xml.open("GET", url, false)
xml.send(null)
```

The nodeList is empty in the console log. However, when I run the code, querySelectorAll('.msDetails-Row'), on the actual URL, it works.

Comment: It sounds like xml.responseText might not be valid HTML. You could look at the Network tab in your browser's devtools, or log xml.responseText to see if it is indeed valid HTML

Comment: innerHTML do not add items to the DOM.

Comment: Not sure why you're using a synchronous call and not an asynchronous call. Changing `xml.open("GET", url, false)` to `xml.open("GET", url, true)` worked for me when copying your snippet and using a real url.